# How to input local IP address in getJSON

Tags: jquery

Please help.

I want to getJSON information from a local IoT device, this device has no URL but only a fixed IP address 192.168.1.20 and getJSON doesn't accept this.
My IoT device has a small webserver.

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://192.168.1.20/', function (data) {
    // rest off code
    });
});
```

Many thanks Maarten

Comment: Have you tried just `$getJSON('/', ... )` ?

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Comment: You would need to enable CORS on the device server if you are making this request in a browser

Comment: Take a look at JSONP, it worked for me

Comment: This is simply a standard cross-origin problem. If your IoT device had a domain name, you would experience the exact same problem. As mentioned elsewhere, the solution is either to have the device serve CORS headers, have the device serve script files that include blocks of data in them (JSONP), or perform the fetch outside of a browser (e.g., on a server that is not cross-origin or does serve CORS headers) and pass the result to the browser.

Comment: The error message I get is:
'Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead'

I'm using a simalair script as from Highcharts, however they get their data from a real URL
When I modify my script using the above URL it works.

@Michael: on your advice I tried : $.getJSON('/','http://192.168.1.20/',....)
However I get the same error message.
To be honest I have no experience with CORS.

PeterPan666: can you give an JSONP example ? Do I need to modify the code in the IoT server ? or something in the javascript.

Maarten

Comment: If the current page being served is at the address `'http://192.168.1.20/'` you should have no problems. Also what I meant was this : `$.getJSON('/', function (data) {...});` that will always do the GET from the current URL.

Comment: @Michael: I try to get the data from a different server as where the webpage with javascript runs. The data comes from an IoT device, this has a different IP as the server.

Comment: @PeterPann666: I understand the JSONP, however my IoT server is very simple, it run on an 8-bit AVR. So it can't handle callback=? .

Comment: @apsillers: Perhaps I made it to complicated using JSON? The Javascript only needs a few bytes from the IoT device. I now packed them in JSON, but perhaps there are much more simple solutions to get a few bytes from an IP device into Javascript code ??

Comment: If the IoT device is going to participate in JSONP, it needs to serve an executable JavaScript script when asked that includes the data. For example, if the bytes you want to send are the number `123`, you need to have the IoT device serve a script like `doThing(123);` when the requester asks for e.g., `/scriptWithVal.js`. The requesting page defines what `doThing` does when the remote script loads and runs (e.g., `function doThing(v) { alert(v); };`). That's how JSONP works. (It actually has nothing to do with JSON, but that's a popular format to use for the function argument.)

Comment: The same-origin policy makes it deliberately difficult or impossible for information from one origin (domain, port, and scheme) to be read by a script running on a page served from a different origin. CORS is the correct way for a server (here, your IoT device) to relax the same-origin policy. Your server should send CORS headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allow a page from another origin to read its resources.

Comment: @assillers: Thanks for your explanation. I think this is the way out. Can you give a small code example of the requesting page, where it request from the IoT IP address ?

Comment: @apsillers: I succeeded to have the IoT device serving a Javascript with the data. The drawback however is that the data is loaded only once when the whole page was loaded. I was hoping to refresh the data (only) eaxh few seconds or so. Anyhow thanks.

Comment: @Maarten_H That's great! Now you just need to periodically run a JSONP request for the script; see https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/ for jQuery's JSONP support and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval for `setInterval` documentation

Comment: @assillers: It works fine with setInterval now. Thanks a lot